# Not able to checkin my code in github

Tags: github

This is my first day at using GITHUB and I am stuck with this issue despite lot of googling. Her are the steps which I have done so far

cloned a repository

```
git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git
```

Now since I don't want to corrupt the main branch, I created my own branch

```
git branch validation
```

Now I switched to my branch

```
git checkout validation
```

Now I made all my changes locally. After this I created the remote branch

```
git remote add validation https://github.com/OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git
```

Now I try to uploaded all my code

```
git push complete-me-code-sample validation
```

it asks me for user name and password and then gives me an error

```
fatal: 'complete-me-code-sample' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

But isn't git open for everyone? or do I need to contact the owner of this project and ask for rights? if yes, what rights I should ask for?

At this point of time, I am finding too much information and its hard for me to proceed without doing a PHD.

Can you please tell me how I can checkin my code ... as well as point me to a resource which can teach me git without too much RTFM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is simple and it's [git](/questions/tagged/git) related, not [github](/questions/tagged/github). Here it is:

> ```
> Now I made all my changes locally. After this I created the remote branch
>
> git remote add validation https://github.com/OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git
> ```

**This is not how you create a remote branch**, in here you've added another origin (named validation), which basically is another clone of the same repo. You said that other repo is located at that address which is not true, as nothing exists there.

When you `git push` if the remote branch doesn't exist it is created by default, so if you simply skipped that step the branch would have been created fine.

The correct and optimised steps should have been:

```
git clone https://github.com/OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git

// Creates and changed branch at the same time
git checkout -b validation

// You'll need to commit files first, just in case you missed that
git commit -am "my sample commit"

// Depending on how you set up the repo git push could be enough
git push origin validation
```

Try this and let me know how it went.

Comment: still getting this error 

Username for 'https://github.com': abhitechdojo
Password for 'https://abhitechdojo@github.com':
remote: Permission to OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git denied to abhitechdojo.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/OfficeDev/Complete-Me-Code-Sample.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: i forked the project and then I was able to checkin. but is forking the right thing to do? how would I contribute to the original project?

Comment: do you have write access on that repo?

Comment: you know send a pull request with your changes to the original repo. https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests